# AngularJS and Cross Domain POST

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

i have a question regarding CORS requests with HTTP Authorization header:

It seems to me that web browser is not sending Authorization header with POST request, is there any way around this?

Here is my Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }]);

    app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.insert = function () {

            $http.post('http://my.api.com/Insert',
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    data: {
                        'Code': 'test data'
                    },
                    withCredentials: true
                });
        };
    });
```

On server side i have this in my web.config

```
<httpProtocol >
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: did u find a solution for that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using the `$http.post` incorrectly. The second parameter is the ***data*** you need to send to server, you cannot set headers like this. In your case, it will send ***the whole object*** 
as ***JSON payload***

Try this:

```
$http({
       url:'http://my.api.com/Insert',
       method:"POST",
       headers: {
                  'Authorization': 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       },
       data: {
              'Code': 'test data'
       }
  });
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks! Just one more thing i had to fix is that you cannot use withCredentials: true if you have Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Comment: @Veshraj Joshi: What is your case?

Comment: so the Basic  dGVzdDp0ZXN0 part, whtas that about? is the ' dGVzdDp0ZXN0' code mandatory?

Comment: @khanh To i am trying to make html files on local machine with angular js and on domain laravel 5.1(php framework); and works fine if html files are on same domain; otherwise didnot work, but amazing thing is that "get " method works fine from everywhere with above code.

Comment: @Dezmen Ceo Sykes: the ' dGVzdDp0ZXN0' code is mandatory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication . But it should have different value based on current user.

Comment: @Veshraj Joshi: it's weird to me when you said the "get" ajax request works fine everywhere (even for cross-domain). Is CORS enabled on your server? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

withCredentials - {boolean} - whether to to set the withCredentials flag on the XHR object. See requests with credentials for more information.