# How to use https in angularjs?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, https

I am sending password and username to server in http. Is there a way to use secure https, so the passwords won't be sent in plain text.

My code:

```
wikiServices.service('authService', function($http, $q){

var userLogin = function(username, password){
    return $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"login/" + username + ":" + password
    });
};
```

If i change the $http to $https i get:
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $httpsProvider <- $https <- authService

Comment: you just need to put the full url `https://blah.com` into url (also be wary of [cross domain posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343316/angularjs-and-cross-domain-post))

Answer (score -1):

The URL needs to be written with the https tag in front. Like this:

```
url:"https:/login/" + username + ":" + password
```

If this doesn't work check out this documentation:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

The http headers can be hidden as the example shows.

http://blog.auth0.com/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/ also a good tutorial on how it works.